# Store the complete log output from the logger object as a string

Tags: json, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

Is it possible to store the complete log output from the logger object as a string? I looked on the internet for this but couldn't find a working solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be using a StreamHandler with a text stream:

```
import logging
from io import StringIO

text_stream = StringIO()
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=text_stream)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.warning('some log')
logger.warning('some other log')

logs_as_string = text_stream.getvalue()
print(logs_as_string) # 'some log\nsome other log\n'
```